# I need help to a difficulty I am having

Tags: java

I am trying to make a simple program that calculates all the prime numbers, but for some reason the output of this is:

0
1
2
3
Build Successful

Here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    boolean per = true;
    for(int num = 0;;num++)
    {
        per = true;
        for(int div = 1;div<=num;div++)
        {
            if(num % div != 0)
            {
                per = false;
            }
        }
        if(per == true)
        {
            System.out.println(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Yes I have tried using almost anything and have spent the past 4 hours researching this problem.

Comment: Have you included in your research walking through your code with a few examples on the whiteboard?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is off.

Try using System.out.println(...) to walk through your code (or use a debugger).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean per = true;
  for (int num = 0;; num++) {
    per = true;
    for (int div = 1; div <= num; div++) {
      if (num % div == 0) {
        System.out.println(num + " is divisible by "+div);
        per = false;
        break;  //stop looping at first opportunity
      }
    }
    if (per == true) {
      System.out.println(num + " is prime");
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
0 is prime
1 is divisible by 1
2 is divisible by 1
3 is divisible by 1
4 is divisible by 1
5 is divisible by 1
6 is divisible by 1
7 is divisible by 1
8 is divisible by 1
9 is divisible by 1
```

So, this tells you that obviously you should start your loop at 2, since all numbers are divisible by 1.

If you change the inner loop to this:

```
(int div = 2; div < num; div++)
```

You get:

```
2 is prime
3 is prime
4 is divisible by 2
5 is prime
6 is divisible by 2
7 is prime
8 is divisible by 2
9 is divisible by 3
```

(Note that I started the outer loop at 2 since 0 and 1 are not usually considered prime.

Comment: also some performance improvments, on the for loop, instead of div < num you can do div <= sqrt(num), this will speed up the program because if a number isnt prime it will have a number that can / it that is <= than his sqrt, also, exept for 2 all prime numbers ar odd numbers, so that can be another speed up